# Sequelize, How can i find from multiple tables

Tags: orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm using Sequelize to select from multiple tables, looking for a way to include a constraint on E.tmpField
currently, the example below doesn't work...

```
await A.findOne({

                include: [
                    {
                        model: B,
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: C,
                                include: [D, E],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        model: F,
                        include: [G],
                    },
                ],
                where: {
                    name: { [Op.in]: nameList },
                    $and: [{ '$E.tmpField$': 100 }],
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify where options for each eager loaded model:

```
await A.findOne({
    where: {
        name: { [Op.in]: nameList } // Where option for model A
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: B,
            include: [
                {
                    model: C,
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: D
                        },
                        {
                            model: E,
                            where: {
                                tmpField: 100 // Where option for model E
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            model: F,
            include: [G],
        },
    ]
});
```